# Ionic Unable to view object

Tags: ionic-framework, ng-controller

I am unable to view object in the page. Can someone help to take a look what am i missing here ? I have my code in code pen http://codepen.io/ccrash/pen/wWXVGj . Really need someone to help out. When I clicked on the list in mainpage, it should bring me to the second page where user details should be displayed. But, I am not seeing any details here.

**In App.js**

```
.state('app.person', {
    url: "/person/:personId",
    views: {
        'menuContent': {
            templateUrl: "templates/people-detail.html",
            controller: 'PersonDetailCtrl'
         }
      }
})
```

**Controller.js**

```
.controller('PersonDetailCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, Session, $state, $ionicHistory) {    

    var Persons = [
        {id: 1, name: 'Mickey', Tel: '12345'},
        {id: 2, name: 'Donald', Tel: '23444'},
        {id: 3, name: 'Goofy', Tel: '12323'}
    ];  
    $scope.person = Persons[$stateParams.personId];
})
```

In people-detail.html

```
<ion-content ng-controller="PersonDetailCtrl" class="background">
  <div>
  <i class="{{person.id}}"> </i>
  </div>
  <div>
  <i class="{{person.name}}"> </i>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

This `$scope.person = Persons[$stateParams.locationId];` should be `$scope.person = Persons[$stateParams.personId];`

Comment: I changed it to personId as you adviced. Still unable to see anything from the page.

Comment: Anyone else can take a look at my codepen  http://codepen.io/ccrash/pen/wWXVGj  and give some idea why the view detail is not working ?

Comment: Glad you solved it. Sorry for not checking your messages before.